# How to make links, leading to themselves, unclickable in the whole project? Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, hyperlink, laravel-8

Task: no link should lead to itself.

What I did:

*view.blade.php:*

```
<a href="{{route('namedRoute')}}
@if(route('namedRoute') == Request::url())
        class="disabled"
@endif
>Some link</a>
```

*style.css:*

```
a.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    text-decoration: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

But it's not global. There can be many links, and doing it manually to every link — not the right way. Maybe, it's possible to do somehow in middleware?

Comment: You could use javascript for something like this.

Comment: Yep, maybe I should. It seems, there is no simple solution on backend only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is mandatory to lead those links to themselves, you maybe could:

1. use `<a href="#">` for that (but you will have to change in every template you have that href value)

```html
<div>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Maybe, you could use javascript:void(), is a way to go to as a substitute for "#"

2. Using Javascript, add an event listener for every `<a>` element in the web and set is `href` to `window.location.href` (this will change dynamically)
3. Disable all the hrefs using javascript.

Comment: Personally for me it's not useful, because I work with backend only and know nothing about js. But I'll wait a few days, and if no one advises something in php, or exact instruction in js, I'll accept your answer. Thank you for trying to help, anyway.

Comment: You could learn what you need from 'freecodecamp', but if that is the case, you could use the option 1, is the most practical and easy, when devs want to make links to not redirect to anywhere else, we use `<a href="#">` or sometimes, leaving it empty sometimes works too `<a href="">`

Comment: That won't work, link should be unclickable at all, and look like plain text.

Comment: So, maybe you should look this article: `https://codewithhugo.com/disable-html-anchor/`

Comment: I know, how to disable link — I did it with css trick. Not the best way, but it works. The problem is to do it globally.